# Mensagem de erro sobre algo que não existe na aplicação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ao executar a minha aplicação está aparecendo essa mensagem, mas não existe esse parâmetro. Eis a mensagem de erro:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="AgendaContato.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %> 
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="AgendaContato.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Comment: Cadê a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Isso não é mensagem de erro, é código

Comment: Se aparece isso quando você abre a aplicação *no browser*, é porque o código ASP não está sendo interpretado pelo servidor. Tem certeza de que seu servidor está rodando?

Comment: sim pq eu executo a aplicacao, e o estranho que nem esse Inherits="AgendaContato.MvcApplication" nao existe, agendacontato

Comment: Por que está declarado duas vezes?

Comment: foi sem querer @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Ainda não está claro pra gente qual é a mensagem de erro. Você poderia tirar um print da tela de erro e colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: Obg @CiganoMorrisonMendez deu certo, acontece que eu mudei o namespace do meu controle e estava aparecendo esse erro ou mensagem no meu navegador entao renomiei o arquivo globalasax,  e deu certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Global.asax` não aceita essa declaração em duplicidade:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="AgendaContato.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Verifique também se o arquivo está íntegro.

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio @Cigano Morrison Mendez, encontrei a solucao, marquei sua resposta como correta.